# .htaccess code to deny direct access to images, but still show them on the website

Tags: image, .htaccess, url

I have a problem with HTACCESS, that i'm not able to resolve.

this morning was the first time i heared about this solution to my problem: people who come on my website and stole my images, using them on others websites and making money on them.

To stop this, i want to deny direct access to images, but still show them on the website pages. My folder structure is like:

reader/MANGANAME/CHAPTERFOLDERS/images

I tryed a lot of solutions, but all them did not show images. The only thing i cannot do is put a file in the "CHAPTER" folder.

This is the website, please include the correct URL in your solution, if it need. http://acg2048animeversion.altervista.org/reader/
And please tell me WHERE create the .htaccess file, is the first time i use it.

sorry for my poor english.